# How to convert to float a string representation of exponetial number with no "e"

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I have a text file of alpha-numeric data in a fixed field format, but the format varies from line to line, so I can't do a fixed field read.
I'm reading line by line, identifying the record type, and slicing according to the format of that record type.  Here's an example with $Comments and three data records split into two lines.  (BTW, the data lines are split due to this being a format that goes back to the old "IBM punch cards", or "Hollerith" cards, which were limited to 80 columns, with the last eight columns reserved for serial numbers in case you dropped your cards you put them into a card sorter:-)

```
MOMENT*  3               15              0              1.00297+9
*       .123092         -.984732        -.123092
$ Nodal Forces of Load Set : Force
FORCE*   1               15              0              1.00297+9
*       .123092         -.984732        -.123092
MOMENT*  3               15              0              1.00297+9
*       .123092         -.984732        -.123092
```

Here's where I'm running into trouble:
Python appears to be having trouble converting the exponential format.
Consider the last field of the second to last line:

```
In [50]: Card1
Out[50]: 'MOMENT*  3               15              0              1.00297+9'
```

Slicing that last field I get:

```
Card1[54:]
Out[49]: '  1.00297+9'
```

If I then strip the white space and convert the string to a float, I get an "invalid literal for float()".

```
float(str.strip(Card1[54:]))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-52-64ddef289a29>", line 1, in <module>
    float(str.strip(Card1[54:]))

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.00297+9
```

Clearly we know how to interpret "1.00297+9", but Python seems to require an "E" or "e" to recognize this as scientific notation:

```
float(str.strip(Card1[54:]).replace("+","E"))
Out[53]: 1002970000.0
```

My problem lies with the negative exponents on negative numbers.  Obviously replace() will break a negative number with a negative exponent by turning  "-123.45-3" into "E123.45E3".

Ideally, there would be some easy way to tell Python to just use the + or - at the end of the number to recognize an exponential.

The only thing I can come up with is to splice the string into parts, as follows.  Although this works, it's not elegant...there has to be a better way.

```
In[56]: String="-1.6486-5"
In[57]: float(String[0:1]+String[1:].replace("-","E-"))
Out[57]: -1.6486e-05
```

Comment: Why isn't it elegant to convert a non-standard float literal to a literal that `float()` is able to parse? Sometimes annoying technical problems require annoying solutions. What you have seems fine.

Comment: Yes, "annoying" is a the right expression! I didn't realize that omitting the "E" was non-standard.  I've seen it for so long, it just looked "normal" to me, but I'll accept that it is non-standard.  In which case, my solution is likely as good as it's going to get.
Thanks!
I learned FORTRAN in 1977 and I'm very impressed with Python's elegance.  I'm fairly new at Python and had convinced myself that there had to be a better way...perhaps not.

Comment: With Python there usually *is* a more elegant way, but this particular case seems hard to handle nice. Regular expressions are the principled way, but are borderline overkill in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a RegEx replacement
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub
and match as EITHER +/- 
e.g. (start)(0+ digits)**(exactly 1 digit)(+ or -)(1+ digits)** 
or trying 2 replacements one after the other with + and - respectively

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is non-standard notation for an exponential, I don't expect anything better than what I came up with: (Changed the replace to an "e" since that's what Python returns.)

```
In[56]: String="-1.6486-5"
In[57]: float(String[0:1]+String[1:].replace("-","e-"))
Out[57]: -1.6486e-05
```

Thanks to all who commented!